Deprecated struct constructor syntax
I am migrating an old C++ Library with much of the code > 20 years old. I came upon a struct declaration with what I think is intended to be a constructor that looks this :
struct PROPERTIES_PRESENT2
{
    bool PropertyPresence[13];

    struct PROPERTIES_PRESENT2(void)
    {
        memset((&PropertyPresence), 0, (sizeof(bool) * 13));
    }
};

This is not compiling today with modern compilers. I think I can make it work by removing the 'struct' before the constructor. But what I'm hoping for help on is : did older standards of C++ require the 'struct' before the constructor as seen above? And can anyone confirm the behaviour really would have been that of a constructor and not some long forgotten thing with side effects I should be aware of?
My 'converted' version :
struct PROPERTIES_PRESENT
{
    bool PropertyPresence[13];
    
    PROPERTIES_PRESENT(void)
    {
        memset((&PropertyPresence), 0, (sizeof(bool) * 13));
    }      
};


The new version could be struct PROPERTIES_PRESENT {     bool PropertyPresence[13]{}; };

It might help knowing for which compiler this was originally written, given that it must have been pre-standardization.

I've never seen struct required (or allowed) on a constructor.  I started programming in C++ in 1990, using SAS/C++, Lattice C++, Comeau C++, Turbo C++.  Maybe before then...?

It actually looks like some form of "Objective-C++" (Objective-C\C++ mixed language). At that point code sematintics are under big question mark.

Since the name is all uppercase, is there any chance that it's a macro that will be expanded to something else?

Note that "deprecated" is a technical term in the C++ standard; it means that the feature might go away in the future. This syntax has never been legal C++, so there's nothing to deprecate.

Modern version, if you identified language correctly, would be:
struct PROPERTIES_PRESENT
{
    bool PropertyPresence[13] = {};    
};

EDIT: Out of modern compilers, Visual Studio, even latest v.19 accepts this (https://godbolt.org/z/Ts461qM74). This is their style from early times, around VisualStudio 1.0 - 2.0.


did older standards of C++ require the 'struct' before the constructor as seen above?

No, it was never well-formed syntax in ISO C++.
I have never seen this syntax, so I unfortunately can't answer the rest of the question.
